# config parser not returning correct variable - leaves out ( ) around words

Tags: python, configparser

I have a script that takes some data in an excel file and sorts it and adds some colors to some key things....
I'm using an external .ini file because it needs to change sometimes based on the users needs for the day

the ini file basically looks like this

```
[section]
#Color 1
color01 = ('00FCC84E')
cat1 = ('Item1','Item2')

#Color 2
color02 = ('00F4426E')
cat2 = ('Thingy Size 5/16')
```

My Script portion that uses Config Parser does this

```
import configparser
from configparser import ConfigParser
from ast import literal_eval
config = ConfigParser()
config.read("MyFile.ini")
config.sections()

def variables(section):
    dict1 = {}
    options = config.options(section)
    for option in options:
        try:
            dict1[option] = config.get(section, option)
            if dict1[option] == -1:
                DebugPrint("skip: %s" % option)
        except:
            print("exception on %s!" % option)
            dict1[option] = None
    return dict1


color01V = literal_eval(config['ConfigFile']['color01'])
color02V = literal_eval(config['ConfigFile']['color02'])

cat01V = literal_eval(config['ConfigFile']['cat1'])
cat02V = literal_eval(config['ConfigFile']['cat2'])

print(cat01V)
print(cat02V)
```

this returns

```
('Item1','Item2')
Thingy Size 5/16
```

Why does the 2nd string return without the () and how do I fix it.

I actually NEED the () to appear when I use the variable later

Comment: It's because you're using `literal_eval()` which expects/requires Python syntax. You used `cat2 = ('Thingy Size 5/16',)` in the .ini file, the expression will evaluate to a `tuple` of one item: `('Thingy Size 5/16',)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting value of "cat1" in quotations?

```
[section]
color01 = ('00FCC84E')
cat1 = "('Item1','Item2')"
...
cat2 = "('Thingy Size 5/16')"
```

Comment: It appears to not work correctly because it colors EVERYTHING that 2nd color
even if I put " around it

If I put the exact words in place as ('Thingy Size 5/16')
it colors just the items containing "Thingy Size 5/16"

Comment: so I tried something last night as a test
it appears to be a problem with how config parser is handling the single vs multiple arguments.

Comment: If I use 2 or more items, its completely find... but a single items and the script doesnt work

Comment: so if I use `"Item1" , "Item2"`, it retruns `('Item1' , 'Item2')`                                                 
if I use `"Item1Only"` it returns `Item1Only`